# JSON reply parse on JS

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, share, counter

I need to parse reply from server, have a code:

```
$.getJSON('http://connect.mail.ru/share_count?callback=1&url_list=http://www.google.com&func=test', function(data) {
      $('#ml_counter').text(data);
});
```

as a reply on http://connect.mail.ru/share_count?callback=1&url_list=http://www.google.com&func=test request server gives:

```
test(
{
 "http://www.google.com":{"shares":574,"clicks":65}
});
```

How can I get "574" from this?

Comment: `.text(data.test.shares);`

Answer (score 2):

```
callback: function(result) {
    var yourVal = result['http://www.google.com'].shares;
}
```

In your situation:

```
.text(data['http://www.google.com'].shares);
```

Note that returning the url as a parameter isn't really comforting. You're way better of returning just the child object or a list of domain-objects (where one of the properties is something like `url` and another is the `{ shares .... }` object.